# Sub-setting words in data frame with specific length of word

Tags: r, string, data-manipulation

I have data frame like

```
description
csi
ssi
o 
of
in 
over
mss
improvement
channel
```

I want to extract words having length 1-2 and result should be a data frame having following output:

```
description
o
of
in
```

Can any one please help using R-programming

Comment: thanks akrun...it works for me

Comment: You should tick the 'accept answer' check, then.

Comment: now if I want to remove words with length 2 from main data frame then what code should I write

Comment: If you want to keep the rest, you could just replace the `<3` in akrun's code with `>2`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We can apply the `nchar` on the 'description' column to create a logical index for subsetting the rows

```
df1[nchar(df1$description)<3,, drop = FALSE]
#     description
#3           o
#4          of
#5          in
```

Or use `subset` so that by default it is `drop = FALSE`

```
subset(df1, nchar(description) < 3)
```